Why is my trained model not recognizing new images that are different from the test dataset?
I had been training a model to classify a bunch of different images by different labels, namely 2 at first, and if it was working well, I would add more labels to train. I've gotten good results from training accuracy and precision that tested the model during training against a test dataset, however when I try to test the model against new images that weren't a part of the training or test dataset.

This is the code I used to train the model. I used efficentnet_v2-m since my dataset consists of 3.5k images split into 2 labels so ~1.7k for each label.
I just don't understand why is my trained model not recognizing any new images that are from the same set of images that were used for training, but they're different ones, which makes sense, since I shouldn't test the model on the same images I used for training.
import os
import csv
import copy
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.optim import Adam
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torchvision.models import efficientnet_v2_m
from torch.utils.data import random_split, DataLoader
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, precision_score

# ---------------------------
# Configuration and Setup
# ---------------------------

# Directory to save models and logs
save_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Coding/Models")
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)

# CSV file to save training metrics
csv_file = os.path.join(save_dir, "training_metrics.csv")

# Initialize CSV file with column headers (if it doesn't exist)
def initialize_csv():
    if not os.path.exists(csv_file):
        with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([
                "Epoch", "Training Loss", "Validation Loss", 
                "Validation Accuracy", "Validation Precision", "Learning Rate"
            ])

# Device configuration (using M1 Pro GPU or CPU)
device = torch.device("mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"Using device: {device}")

# ---------------------------
# Data Loading and Preprocessing
# ---------------------------

# Define normalization and augmentation transformations
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((600, 1200)),  # Resize to 1200x600 pixels
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),  # Data augmentation: Random horizontal flip
    transforms.RandomRotation(15),      # Data augmentation: Random rotation
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.2, contrast=0.2, saturation=0.15, hue=0.05),  # Data augmentation: Color jitter
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
])

# Define validation and test transformations
val_test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((600, 1200)),  # Resize to 1200x600 pixels
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
])

# Load the dataset (organized by class in folders)
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='/Users/X/Desktop/FinalDatasets/X', transform=train_transform)

# Split the dataset into training (70%), validation (20%), and testing (10%)
dataset_size = len(dataset)
train_size = int(0.7 * dataset_size)
val_size = int(0.2 * dataset_size)
test_size = dataset_size - train_size - val_size

train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])

# Override the transform for validation and test datasets
val_dataset.dataset.transform = val_test_transform
test_dataset.dataset.transform = val_test_transform

# Create DataLoaders for each split
batch_size = 2  # Increased batch size for better performance
num_workers = 0  # Adjust based on your system
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=num_workers)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=num_workers)

print(f"Dataset sizes - Train: {train_size}, Validation: {val_size}, Test: {test_size}")

# ---------------------------
# Model Definition with Fine-Tuning
# ---------------------------

from torchvision.models import efficientnet_v2_m

# Function to create the model with fine-tuning
def EfficientNetV2_M_custom_finetune(num_classes=2, fine_tune_at_layer=-3):
    model = efficientnet_v2_m(pretrained=True)  # Load pre-trained EfficientNetV2-M
    
    # Freeze all layers except the last 'fine_tune_at_layer' layers
    if fine_tune_at_layer != 0:
        for name, param in model.named_parameters():
            # Example: fine_tune_at_layer=-5 to unfreeze last 5 layers
            layer_num = int(name.split('.')[1]) if len(name.split('.')) > 1 and name.split('.')[1].isdigit() else -1
            if layer_num < fine_tune_at_layer:
                param.requires_grad = False
    else:
        # Freeze all layers except the classifier
        for param in model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
    
    # Modify the classifier for 2 classes
    model.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(model.classifier[1].in_features, num_classes)
    
    return model

# Initialize the model with fine-tuning
model = EfficientNetV2_M_custom_finetune(num_classes=2, fine_tune_at_layer=-5).to(device)

# ---------------------------
# Define Custom Loss Function with Class Weighting
# ---------------------------

class CustomPenaltyLossWithWeights(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, class_weights):
        super(CustomPenaltyLossWithWeights, self).__init__()
        # Incorporate class weights into CrossEntropyLoss
        self.cross_entropy_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
        self.weight_matrix = torch.tensor([
            [0, 1],
            [1, 0],
        ], device=device, dtype=torch.float32)

    def forward(self, outputs, targets):
        # Calculate base CrossEntropyLoss with weights
        base_loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(outputs, targets)

        # Get the predicted class
        predicted_class = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)

        # Apply penalty based on how far the prediction is from the true class
        penalties = self.weight_matrix[targets, predicted_class]

        # Combine the base loss with the penalty (mean of penalties)
        loss = base_loss + torch.mean(penalties)

        return loss

# Calculate class weights (inverse of the class frequencies)
class_counts = [1.7e3, 1.7e3]  # [Class 0 count, Class 1 count]
total_samples = sum(class_counts)
class_weights = torch.tensor([total_samples / count for count in class_counts], dtype=torch.float32).to(device)

# Initialize the custom loss function with weights
criterion = CustomPenaltyLossWithWeights(class_weights)

# ---------------------------
# Optimizer and Scheduler Setup
# ---------------------------

from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau

# Define parameter groups with different learning rates
optimizer = Adam([
    {'params': model.features[: -5].parameters(), 'lr': 1e-5},  # Frozen or low learning rate
    {'params': model.features[-5:].parameters(), 'lr': 1e-4},  # Fine-tuned layers
    {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}     # Newly added classifier
])

# Initialize the learning rate scheduler
scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.5, patience=3)

# ---------------------------
# CSV Logging Functions
# ---------------------------

# Function to log training details to CSV
def log_to_csv(epoch, train_loss, val_loss, val_accuracy, val_precision, learning_rate):
    with open(csv_file, mode='a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([
            epoch, train_loss, val_loss, 
            val_accuracy * 100, val_precision * 100, learning_rate
        ])

# Function to save the model after training
def save_model(model, epoch):
    model_save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, f"cnn_model_epoch_{epoch+1}.pth")
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_save_path)
    print(f"Model saved to {model_save_path}")

# Initialize CSV log file
initialize_csv()

# ---------------------------
# Evaluation Function
# ---------------------------

def evaluate_model(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    true_labels = []
    predicted_labels = []
    val_loss = 0.0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in dataloader:
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            val_loss += loss.item()

            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            true_labels.extend(labels.cpu().numpy())
            predicted_labels.extend(predicted.cpu().numpy())

    # Calculate validation accuracy, precision, and confusion matrix
    accuracy = accuracy_score(true_labels, predicted_labels)
    precision = precision_score(true_labels, predicted_labels, average='macro')
    cm = confusion_matrix(true_labels, predicted_labels)  # Add this line to return the confusion matrix
    return accuracy, val_loss / len(dataloader), precision, cm  # Now return four values

# ---------------------------
# Training Loop with Fine-Tuning
# ---------------------------

num_epochs = 6  # Total number of epochs
unfreeze_epochs = [3, 4, 5]  # Epochs at which to unfreeze more layers

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()  # Set the model to training mode
    running_loss = 0.0

    # Training step
    for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        # Zero the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        running_loss += loss.item()

        # Backward pass and optimize
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Print loss after each batch
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Batch [{batch_idx}/{len(train_loader)}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}")

    # Validation step after each epoch
    val_accuracy, val_loss, val_precision, cm = evaluate_model(model, val_loader)
    average_train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}] Summary - Training Loss: {average_train_loss:.4f}, "
      f"Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Validation Accuracy: {val_accuracy*100:.2f}%, "
      f"Validation Precision: {val_precision*100:.2f}%")

    # Print the confusion matrix
    print("Confusion Matrix (Validation):")
    print(cm)

    # Log the details to CSV
    current_lr = optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']
    log_to_csv(epoch + 1, average_train_loss, val_loss, val_accuracy, val_precision, current_lr)

    # Step the learning rate scheduler based on validation loss
    scheduler.step(val_loss)

    # Save the model at the end of each epoch
    save_model(model, epoch)

    # Unfreeze additional layers at specified epochs
    if epoch + 1 in unfreeze_epochs:
        # Determine the number of layers to unfreeze incrementally
        # This logic assumes that 'features' are indexed; adjust based on actual layer naming
        layers_to_unfreeze = -(5 + (unfreeze_epochs.index(epoch + 1) + 1))
        for param in model.features[layers_to_unfreeze:].parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True
        # Update the optimizer to include newly unfrozen parameters
        optimizer = Adam([
            {'params': model.features[: layers_to_unfreeze].parameters(), 'lr': 1e-5},
            {'params': model.features[layers_to_unfreeze:].parameters(), 'lr': 1e-4},
            {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}
        ])
        print(f"Unfroze additional layers at epoch {epoch+1}")

print("Training complete!")

# ---------------------------
# Testing and Evaluation
# ---------------------------

def test_model(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    true_labels = []
    predicted_labels = []
    test_loss = 0.0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in dataloader:
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            test_loss += loss.item()

            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            true_labels.extend(labels.cpu().numpy())
            predicted_labels.extend(predicted.cpu().numpy())

    # Calculate test accuracy and precision
    accuracy = accuracy_score(true_labels, predicted_labels)
    precision = precision_score(true_labels, predicted_labels, average='macro')
    cm = confusion_matrix(true_labels, predicted_labels)

    print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
    print(f"Test Precision: {precision * 100:.2f}%")
    print("Confusion Matrix:")
    print(cm)

    # Save the metrics to a CSV file with a unique name
    metrics_file = os.path.join(save_dir, f"test_metrics_epoch_{num_epochs}.csv")
    with open(metrics_file, mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["Accuracy", "Precision"])
        writer.writerow([accuracy * 100, precision * 100])
        writer.writerow([])
        writer.writerow(["Confusion Matrix"])
        for row in cm:
            writer.writerow(row.tolist())

    print(f"Test metrics saved to {metrics_file}")

# Test the main model after training
print("\nTesting the main model on the test set:")
test_model(model, test_loader)

print("All evaluations complete!")

```


I suspect there might be a misunderstanding about the mission/purpose of this site.  We're not here to act as a help desk to solve your specific problem.  We're here to answer questions that are likely to be helpful to others in the future.  Your question is such a specific case that it's unlikely this is general enough to be useful to others.  In addition, there is a good chance it is not answerable without reference to the specific datasets.  As such, it's not really a good fit for the Stack Exchange format.

Aha. Very sorry about this then, I'll remove it. But I thought that since its in the domain of data science, I could ask it here.

See, e.g., https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378431/781723, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380942/781723, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4990/2921, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424737/781723.

You are allowed to ask it here, but it's not exactly what the site was designed for.  Stack Exchange was originally designed to enable people to collaborate to build an archive of knowledge, in the form of questions that others might have and high-quality answers to them that will hopefully be helpful both the original asker and to future folks who might have the same question.  I don't think this is strictly enforced, but you might find that your experience is less positive the more you deviate from that purpose.

Separately, I suggest you do some reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/395197/2921, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/266174/2921, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9053/2921

I am familiar with overfitting, however, can I say that I don't think overfitting is the issue I've ran into here? I've ran the training for 6 epochs, and it's enough given that the loss and accuracy don't change much after the 6th epoch.
